# Use a function on every value in an array

Tags: javascript

Iam new to javascript and help is very much appreciated. I have the following array:

```js
let array = 
[{key: "sabc", value: 19},
 {key: "spalabc", value: 21},
 {key: "spalte2", value: 22},
 {key: "spabc2", value: 22},
 {key: "spabce2", value: 23}]
```

I want to have a new array, where all the values are changed through a function (in this case logarithm base 10). So the new array should look like this:

```js
let array = 
[{key: "sabc", value: 1.278753601},
 {key: "spalabc", value: 1.322219295},
 {key: "spalte2", value: 1.342422681},
 {key: "spabc2", value: 1.342422681},
 {key: "spabce2", value: 1.361727836}]
```

I tried forEach, but i dont get the result i want.

Comment: you want to use map. Is simular to foreach but it does exaclty what you want. It maps new values to each item.

Comment: why don't you show us what you tried? Although the idiomatic way to do this is with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @John : that will mutate your original array, hence, not quite different from something, you would do with `.forEach()` (paying attention though, that `.forEach()` itself returns `undefined`)

Comment: `forEach` doesn't have to mutate the original array, in fact you can easily implement `map` in terms of `foreach`: `arr.map(f)` can be obtained as `const res = []; arr.forEach(elt => res.push(f(elt)); return res;`. (Of course I don't recommend actually doing that when we have `map` already.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map`:

```js
let array = 
[{key: "sabc", value: 19},
 {key: "spalabc", value: 21},
 {key: "spalte2", value: 22},
 {key: "spabc2", value: 22},
 {key: "spabce2", value: 23}]
 
arr = array.map(e => {
  return {...e, value:Math.log10(e['value'])};
});

console.log(...arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = 
[{key: "sabc", value: 19},
 {key: "spalabc", value: 21},
 {key: "spalte2", value: 22},
 {key: "spabc2", value: 22},
 {key: "spabce2", value: 23}]
 
const result = array.map(a => ({ ...a, value: Math.log10(a.value)}))

console.log(result)
```